# Get values from array without iteration

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [column_name] => product_id
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [column_name] => product_name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [column_name] => product_slug
        )

)
```

and I need a array only with the names of the columns:

```
array('product_id', 'product_name', 'product_slug')
```

I made a empty array and iterate the main array like this:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $key => $res) {
    $data[] = $res['column_name'];
}
```

Is there any other method instead of iterating?

Comment: `$data[] = $result[0]['column_name'];` wouldn't that work?

Comment: No cus $result[0] would return only the first item no?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running `PHP > 5.5` then try to use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function. Like this:

```
$data = array_column($result, 'column_name');
print_r($data);
```

If your `PHP < 5.5` then kindly use this:

```
//Signature: array array_column ( array $input , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key ] )
if( !function_exists( 'array_column' ) ) {

    function array_column( array $input, $column_key, $index_key = null ) {

        $result = array();
        foreach( $input as $k => $v )
            $result[ $index_key ? $v[ $index_key ] : $k ] = $v[ $column_key ];

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note to @Ionvasile This is a nice clean solution. But just for reference, this just moves the array iteration from something you wrote to something someone else wrote. It did not remove the array iteration! With arrays come array iteration, there is no way round it

Comment: @RiggsFolly But I guess using inbuilt function would be faster compare to user defined functions!! Isn't it?

Comment: Yes quite probably, as this is a piece of compiled `C` code you are running. I was not complaining about your answer, just making a comment to the questioner

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I understand, But let us provide bit faster solution to lon vasile. :D

Comment: Absolutely. Like I said earlier. **I was not complaining about your answer** just reminding the questioner that the array still has to be iterated over by something as that is the only way to get data out of an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_column() in you are using PHP > 5.5.

```
$data = array();
$data = array_column($result, 'column_name');
print_r($first_names);
```

If your version is less than it, add this code:

```
<?php
if (! function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column(array $input, $columnKey, $indexKey = null) {
        $array = array();
        foreach ($input as $value) {
            if ( ! isset($value[$columnKey])) {
                trigger_error("Key \"$columnKey\" does not exist in array");
                return false;
            }
            if (is_null($indexKey)) {
                $array[] = $value[$columnKey];
            }
            else {
                if ( ! isset($value[$indexKey])) {
                    trigger_error("Key \"$indexKey\" does not exist in array");
                    return false;
                }
                if ( ! is_scalar($value[$indexKey])) {
                    trigger_error("Key \"$indexKey\" does not contain scalar value");
                    return false;
                }
                $array[$value[$indexKey]] = $value[$columnKey];
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if downvoter explains the reason behind downvoting.

Comment: I will also know what's wrong there and I can improve myself.